# Do all map features appear with difficulty=0?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Do all map features, e.g. villages and ruins, appear if `difficulty=0` is set on my SMP Minecraft server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

World Generation (including the generation of structures) is not affected by the difficulty setting of the world.

You can find villages/strongholds on peaceful as well as on hard.